# using Hibernate ORM in an EJB Project in Myeclipse with glassfish and mysql data base

Tags: mysql, glassfish, ejb-3.0, hibernate-mapping, myeclipse

I am new to J2EE development and its frameworks, so I'm leads to create a J2EE application usign Myeclipse,glassfish ans mysql as SGBD ... I need to create a project EJB3 session I have to use Hibernate3 ORM .. My concern is that I've worked with hibernate but in a web project type and not EJB and I really do not know how my project should be like .. I just need to understand the structure of my EJB project because normally we have 2 basic classes: EJBService and EJBserviceRemote .. EJBService, containing all my methods that I would need to call from my client (a web project for exemple) and EJBServiceRemote which contains the signature of each method .. so where do I rank the DAO classes generated by Hibernate ORM and how to call them?? shoukd I copy their code in EJBService and then declare in EJBServiceRemote to be able to call them by my client??

SOS I'm really disturbed

Comment: There is a tutorial on creating an EJB3 project in MyEclipse: http://docs.myeclipseide.com/topic/com.genuitec.myeclipse.ejb.doc/html/quickstarts/ejb3/index.html?cp=1_9_2_2_2#Creating and there is a Hibernate tutorial also. Just combine them. Normally a client wouldn't call DAO methods, just the business methods you expose on the Service. All database manipulation is handled on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add all the jars that you're using in your ejb project to the following glassfish directory :

1. C:/..../glassfish/lib
2. C:/..../glassfish/domains/"your domain name"/lib

Answer (score 0):

*Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion*

may be you're missing one of the hibernate jars (hibernate-core.jar) or maybe you have an older version of hibernate + a recent one at the same time in your classpath.

Comment: ok yesss you're right i didn't found that jar so i've download it and put it into my lib and classpath but it stills don't work i got the same error !!

Comment: don't forget to vote or mark the answer that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

ok everything is working now here is my methode to show data:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public int[][] afficheProduitsStockList(){

    int j,a;

    ProduitsStockDAO stockdao = new ProduitsStockDAO();
    List<ProduitsStock> LPdt = stockdao.findAll();
    a=LPdt.size();
    int t[][]=new int[a][3];

    Iterator it = LPdt.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
    for(j=0;j<t.length;j++){        
        ProduitsStock pdt = (ProduitsStock)it.next();                   

          t[j][0]=pdt.getCodeStock();
          t[j][1]=pdt.getCodePdt();
          t[j][2]=pdt.getQtePdt();
          } }
    return t;
}
```

and everything works !

Thank you all :)